# How to produce different outcome from a single SQL check

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a table Register. I would like to check three data from the textboxes with the data in table for finding duplicate and also like to produce seperate popup messages for each compare. i.e, if username is already used, I want to display username exist. Likewise for AdminNo and RegitrationNo.
Backend code is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            String str = "INSERT INTO Register (Name,AdminNo,RegisterNo,Branch,DoB,Address,Mobile,Email,Username,Password) VALUES('" + TextBoxName.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt64(TextBoxadmin.Text) + "','" + TextBOxreg.Text + "','" + DrpBranch.SelectedItem + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(DoB.Text) + "','" + address.Text + "','" + mobno.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + user.Text + "','" + pass.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the insert function to table.

```
private bool UserExist()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Register Where AdminNo='"+Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxadmin.Text)+"' OR Username='"+user.Text+"' OR RegisterNo='"+TextBOxreg.Text+"'"); 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

This is my duplicate checking function, where you can see I checked the duplicate with the OR operator.
If any duplicate is found true is returned. 
Please provide a way for finding the duplicates seperately and displaying seperate messages.

Comment: You should definitely learn parameterized queries. Your code is open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: look here it is simple and clean    http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Registration-Form-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on C++ or MS SQL, but I think this solution might work. I apologize if the syntax isn't quite correct (I don't have an easy way to verify it), so please feel free to adapt as needed, but the idea is as follows. You would modify the SQL statement as follows:

```
select 
case
    when 
        AdminNo='"+Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxadmin.Text)+"'"
    then
        CAST(1 AS BIT)
    else 
        CAST(0 AS BIT) 
end  as AdminYes,

case
    when 
         Username='"+user.Text+"'"
    then
        CAST(1 AS BIT)
    else 
        CAST(0 AS BIT) 
end  as UsernameYes,

case
    when 
         RegisterNo='"+TextBOxreg.Text+"'"
    then
        CAST(1 AS BIT)
    else 
        CAST(0 AS BIT) 
end  as RegisterNoYes
From Register Where AdminNo='"+Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxadmin.Text)+"' OR Username='"+user.Text+"' OR RegisterNo='"+TextBOxreg.Text+"'"
```

You would execute this query in your: shatement

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement);
```

where the sqlStatement is what I posted above. Then when you work with the reader, you can check rdr.getBoolean(0) if it returns true, then it means that you got the Admin duplicate, if you get rdr.getBoolean(1) as true, then it's a username duplicate, and if you get rdr.getBoolean(3) equal to true, then it's a RegiserNo duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didnt understand the meaning of AdminYes, UsernameYes, RegisterNoYes. I like to pass the value to a .NET class for displaying the result. I think it is not possible to pass this SQL query to it. For example, when username is duplicate I want to set int str as 1.

Comment: See my edits above. The names of AdminYes, UsernameYes, RegisterNoYes don't really matter. The point is that you can then, in your code, check for those boolean values.

Comment: I will check it. I am not so good in working with sql.. Thank you @Artur Charukhchyan

Comment: Your query might potentially return multiple records, in which case the result set is inconclusive - you need to aggregate your results

Answer (score 0):

You should create a stored procedure - and pass your @AdminNo, @UserName and @RegisterNo as parameters.
The stored procedure can return either a 
 - custom user defined type,
 - varchar(max) with contents of xml, or
 - just a ordinary table result set
The actual format does not matter as long as you can "pass" a table (not a scalar response)

The sproc could do something along the lines of

```
Select 'AdminNo' as [FieldName], count(*) as [CountOfRecords] From Register Where AdminNo = @AdminNo
UNION ALL
Select 'UserName', count(*) From Register Where UserName = @UserName 
UNION ALL
Select 'RegisterNo', count(*) From Register Where RegisterNo = @RegisterNo
```

Then, in your UserExist routine, you have to ExecuteReader and read all rows.
You will always have three rows (one for AdminNo, one for UserName, and one for RegisterNo), and you can use the count in each of the rows - if count > 0 then there are duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DemoNameSpace
{
    public class DemoClassDAL
    {
        private CheckResult UserExist()
        {
            CheckResult result = CheckResult.NoDuplicate;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1
                                                    case
                                                        when AdminNo = @AdminNo  then 'AdminExists'
                                                        when Username = @UserName then 'UserExists'
                                                        when RegisterNo = @RegisterNo then 'RegisterNoExists'
                                                    end as Result
                                                  From Register");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                var dbresult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();

                if (dbresult != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    Enum.TryParse(dbresult.ToString(), out result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public enum CheckResult
    {
        NoDuplicate,
        AdminExists,
        UserExists,
        RegisterNoExists
    }
}
```